# AnchorEntity convenience init(plane: classification: minimumBounds) use

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, realitykit

```
// add in viewWillAppear
let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: [.horizontal, .vertical], 
                 classification: [.any], 
                  minimumBounds: [0.01, 0.01])
anchor.name = "loongAnchor"
let boxModel = QDVirtualEntity.box(size: 0.1, corner: 0, color: .red)
anchor.addChild(boxModel)
arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
```

QDVirtualEntity function:

```
public static func box(size: Float, corner: Float, color: UIColor = .orange) -> ModelEntity {
    let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: size, cornerRadius: corner), 
                        materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: color, isMetallic: false)])
    entity.position.y = size / 2.0
    return entity
}
```

After running, I cannot find the added box. Why is that? How does this method work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1：you can set (default)

```
 arView.automaticallyConfigureSession = true
```

After adding the code as above, it will be automatically added when the plane is detected.

2: if you `set automaticallyConfigureSession = false`

```
/// Defaults to ARPlaneDetectionNone.
configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal  or .vertical
```

Answer (score 0):

You code works fine. The only issue could be `minimumBounds` set to [0.01, 0.01]. It's too small. Set it to [0.2, 0.2], so your detected plane will have a robust size. Also track a surrounding environment slower, and you'll see your little box in a room as soon as plane is detected.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: [.horizontal, .vertical], 
                         classification: [.any], 
                          minimumBounds: [0.2, 0.2])
        let boxModel = QDVirtualEntity.box(size: 0.1, corner: 0, color: .green)
        anchor.addChild(boxModel)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }
}

class QDVirtualEntity {
    
    public static func box(size: Float, corner: Float, color: UIColor) -> ModelEntity {
        let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: size, cornerRadius: corner),
                            materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: color,
                                                  isMetallic: false)])
        entity.position.y = size / 2.0
        return entity
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the problem. Because I set `arView.automaticallyConfigureSession = false`. then no setting `configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal`.

Comment: I hope you update a little bit about the use of lidar point cloud. . Then can you help me look at another question [how render mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64796845/how-to-re-render-the-scanned-mesh-content-with-realitykits-arview)? Grateful